# How to create an array from a file in Powershell?

Tags: arrays, powershell, dynamic-arrays

I want to read a file and load all its content to an array, one file line= one array member. from a weird reason- I don't manage to do it, it keep "merging" all the lines into 1 line.
I tried few ways-

1) Fetch the file content to list, and then

```
   `$FilesList = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[String]
   foreach($line in Get-Content $OutputFileName) {

       $FilesList.Add($line)
   }
```

This gives me good list, but then-
        `[String[]]$FilesArray = $FilesList.ToArray();`
And I receive for-
        `$FilesArray[0] -> line1 line2 [0]` 
        `$FilesArray[1] -> line1 line2 [1]`

2) Using the solution- 
         `[string[]]$arrayFromFile = Get-Content -Path  $OutputFileName
         $arrayFromFile = [string[]](Get-Content -Path  $OutputFileName)`
Same result when printing $arrayFromFile[0] and $arrayFromFile[1]

3) Using the solution -
          `[String[]]$arrayFromFile = [IO.File]::ReadAllLines($OutputFileName)`
Same result when printing $arrayFromFile[0] and $arrayFromFile[1]

What am I doing wrong, How can it be that I can create a list but not an array?
The problem is that I need to allow the client to choose between the values, so it is important to me to receive array that I can choose specific location

Comment: [Get-Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7) already returns the file content as an array:  _"For files, the content is read one line at a time and returns a collection of objects"_.  The output is already indexable: `(Get-Content $OutputFileName)[5]`

Comment: And yet, somehow- in 3  different ways, when I try to load the file content into array, the result is an array that each of his 2 lines contains both lines concatenated of the original fille. THe original file contained list of 2 file names, and what I get in the array is-  "file1 file2[0]" and "file1 file2[1]"

Comment: Could be caused by simply referencing the wrong variable. Did you perhaps do something like: `$fileContent = Get-Content $OutputFileName; foreach($line in $fileContent){ $FilesList.Add($fileContent) }`?

Comment: I did something like it-
$FilesList = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[String]

foreach($line in Get-Content $OutputFileName) {
   $FilesList.Add($line)
 
}
This list worked, but I need to convert it to array, and then the problem re-create

Comment: Just to clarify- The file I am trying to read is first build in groovy by appending lines with each line ending with "\n"', as I wrote- I can convert it to list, but can not convert it to array, which is what I need

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't understand the question - you already have an array of strings (the output from `Get-Content $outputFileName`) and you can successfully populate your list from said array. Can you perhaps post the sample contents of a file where it doesn't work for you?

Comment: Hi,
This is the content that I am testing - 
test_m2p_Eyal.fmx (added)
test_m2p_Eyal.fmb (added)

Comment: Hi,
This is the content of the file that I am testing - 

Line 1:  test_m2p_Eyal.fmx (added)

Line 2: test_m2p_Eyal.fmb (added)

(There are here two lines, in each line there are two strings separated by space), however- when I try to convert to array-
For example this code-
[string[]]$arrayTest = @(Get-Content -Path  $OutputFileName);
Write-Output "arrayTest-$arrayTest[0]"
Write-Output "arrayTest-$arrayTest[1]"
What I receive is-

arrayTest-test_m2p_Eyal.fmx (added) test_m2p_Eyal.fmb (added)[0]

arrayTest-test_m2p_Eyal.fmx (added) test_m2p_Eyal.fmb (added)[1]

Comment: Please can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61909025/edit) your question and put this extra info in there? In a comment, it is barely readable..

Answer (score 0):

OK, found the problem. nothing to do with the array.
The problem was that the Write-Output can not receive as a parameter "$array[index]", it then prints the full array, and then the index itself.